# Abnormal behavior of log4go

Tags: logging, go

I found the [log4go](http://code.google.com/p/log4go/w/list) package loses logs from time to time.

Following is a simple code snippet(I moved the `log4go` directory so the following import is ok.):

```
package main
import (
    "log4go"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("fmt")
    log.Println("log")
    log4go.Info("log4go")
    log4go.Info("log4go")
}
```

Then I executed it by `go run test.go`, and the output is as follows:

```
fmt
2013/01/10 15:24:04 log
```

The messages by `log4go` are not written to output.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the issues on `log4go` website, it seems that the `log4go` has a flushing problem.

Becuase it uses a `channel` to write to files, if the `main` exits too fast, the log content will not be written.

So adding a `time.Sleep(time.Second)` to the end of the code snippeet will cause the log content flush.

Comment: yes, log4go, indeed has this flush bug. but I use that `os.Stdout.Sync() ` still not work, but use your method, to add `time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)`, then fix my problem, many thanks!!! for others, can refer my post: [log4go not show log info or only show partly](http://www.crifan.com/go_language_log4go_only_output_part_info/)

Answer (score 3):

**edit**: it seems their getting started page is no more up to date, in fact I had problems getting log4go to print to stdout at all, in the docs for version 3.0.1 they state:

- Usage notes: - The ConsoleLogWriter does not display the source of the message to standard output, but the FileLogWriter does.

That was not reproducible on my box. the only way to have it print to stdout was to flush manually (as @jnml suggested) by calling os.Stdout.Sync() after logging calls.

generally my impression is that the docs of log4go are not maintained lately, the examples are not working, they use deprecated methods and the general behaviour is therefore hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Without even providing at least a link to "log4go" it's not easy to answer this question (hence -1) so let me just guess: There might be a missing call to 'flush' somewhere. Perhaps better report the issue to the package author(s)?

BTW: Also the import path "log4go" is broken, considering the standard/recommended Go setup.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add some code to Close() like below.

```
for i := 10; i > 0 && len(w.rec) > 0; i-- {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

There some rec in w.rec not be saved.

https://github.com/ccpaging/log4go