# Is there a built-in go logger that can roll

Tags: go

Is there a built-in Go logger that can roll a log file when it reaches a file size limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in in logger that currently has this feature.
*log4go*, which you will find recommended when searching, <del>is currently broken.</del> has some [issues](http://code.google.com/p/log4go/issues/list), that lead to messages getting lost (in case the main program exits and some messages are still in the channelbuffer before being written).
this is present in most if not all the examples.

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252766/abnormal-behavior-of-log4go/14257272#14257272)

Comment: Right. I tried to create one, but somehow calling Truncate() on the object returned by os.Open() wouldn't work. So, as a work-around I just reopened the file with O_TRUNC flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Above the [syslog package](http://golang.org/pkg/log/syslog/), which probably is not what you really want, no such thing is in the standard library.

From the 3rd party packages, for example [log4go](http://code.google.com/p/log4go/) claims to have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
import (
    "os"

    "github.com/nikandfor/tlog"
    "github.com/nikandfor/tlog/rotated"
)

func main() {
    f, err := rotated.Create("logfile_template_#.log") // # will be substituted by time of file creation
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    f.MaxSize = 1 << 30    // 1GiB
    f.Fallback = os.Stderr // in case of failure to write to file, last chance to save log message

    tlog.DefaultLogger = tlog.New(tlog.NewConsoleWriter(f, tlog.LstdFlags))

    tlog.Printf("now use it much like %v", "log.Logger")

    log.SetOutput(f) // also works for any logger or what ever needs io.Writer

    log.Printf("also appears in the log")

}
```

- logger https://github.com/nikandfor/tlog
- rotated file https://godoc.org/github.com/nikandfor/tlog/rotated

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.